# mat-form-field floatLabel="never" not working

Tags: angular-material

For some reason using Angular 8 this parameter of never does not work for me on a mat-select.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="never">
   <mat-label>Lesson</mat-label>
   <mat-select [(value)]="selected" (selectionChange)="onMenuChange($event.value)">
   <mat-option value="T1">Lesson 1</mat-option>
   <mat-option value="T2">Lesson 2</mat-option>
   <mat-option value="T3">Lesson 3</mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Always and Auto work, but never won't seem to make it go away.

Comment: `floatLabel="never"` is not supported on mat-select.

Comment: Well, it is on mat-form-field which wraps mat-select. It does work, just not when you have appearance="outline" on it.

Comment: floatLabel works for only some specific combinations on different elements.

Answer (score 4):

#### TLDR:

Just remove the `<mat-label>` and use a *placeholder* on `<mat-form-field>` instead.

---

You can hide the floating label, you just have to approach the 'outline' variant differently. And there is absolutely no need to forcefully override the label via some weird css hack. 

From the Angular Material docs:

> Note: only the legacy appearance supports the `never` option. `never` was originally added as a way to make the floating label emulate the behavior of a standard input placeholder. However the form field now supports both floating labels and placeholders. Therefore in the non-legacy appearances the `never` option has been disabled in favor of just using the placeholder.

So it's actually the intended behavior for the 'outline' variant.

All you have to do is to just use the *placeholder* attribute on `<mat-form-field>` instead of adding a `<mat-label>`.

In your case:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="never" placeholder="Lesson">
   <mat-select [(value)]="selected" (selectionChange)="onMenuChange($event.value)">
      <mat-option value="T1">Lesson 1</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="T2">Lesson 2</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="T3">Lesson 3</mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

So basically people usually add a label they don't even want and need, only to look for css hacks to hide it...

Comment: I'm using Material v14.2.7 - Removing <mat-label> partially worked but adding the placeholder to <mat-form-field> didn't effect it. Then, moving the placeholder into <mat-select> per API doc, does show the placeholder BUT it also brings back <mat-label> as if it was always there. Any ideas on what to do here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

try to use  `floatLabel="never"` or `floatLabel="always"`

Answer (score 3):

Managed to come up with the following scss to imitate the label not floating:

```css
.some-custom-class-name {
  &.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-label {
    transform: none;
    width: initial;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  &.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-outline-gap {
    border-top-color: initial;
  }
  /* Not required, only used to reposition the label slightly
  &.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-label {
    top: 1.54375em;
    margin-top: -0.25em;
  }
  */
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="some-custom-class-name">
  <mat-label>Shouldn't float</mat-label>
  <input matInput>
</mat-form-field>
```

Just append the `some-custom-class-name` class to the `mat-form-field` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is kinda a shortcut of solution [suggest by Dane Brower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57627925/mat-form-field-floatlabel-never-not-working/62908780#62908780).

```css
  ::ng-deep &.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-should-float {
    .mat-form-field-label {
      display: none;
    }

    .mat-form-field-outline-gap {
      border-top-color: initial;
    }
  }
```

In comparison to his solution, this one just removes the label element from DOM (via `display: none`) since we don't need it anymore. We also need `::ng-deep` pseudo-class here since `mat-form-field-...` elements are encapsulated within `mat-form-field`.

<sub>Note: you have to be carefull with `::ng-deep` and try to prefix it with `:host` in order to not apply its style globally (in my case `:host ::ng-deep` didn't work here).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18267

Just add a place holder in the mat-select.

Like this: `<mat-select placeholder="FL">`